# List All domains and data sources use in the domains in Jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

How can i List All domains and data sources use in the domains in Jaspersoft.

i mean i have different domains like audit domains,customer domain etc is there any way to get all domains with tables(Data sources) use in these domains in jaspersoft?

I have around 20 domains and manually going to each domain and listing tables is cubersome so i need some help!

Answer (score 1):

there is not a good way that i have found (i am sure you can dig into the DB) 
one way to get this is to export the domains and it exports to a nice neat XML file. 
As we only use JDBC sources we only need to look for "jdbcTable" and "jdbcQuery" tags to see what a domain is using  this is all in the second 1/2 of the xml.  if you use other datasources you may nee to review the xml to see how Jasper references them in the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.jaspersoft.com/2007/SL/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
   <resources>
     <jdbcTable id="" datasourceId="" tableName="">  
     <jdbcQuery id="" datasourceId="">  
         <query>  select * from table <\query>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is for identifying Adhoc Views that depend on Domains, but I believe you could implement a similar solution with domains that depend on Datasources.

In the domain I created a derived table [AdhocViewName].
The query for this domain is:

```
    SELECT   a.id               as AdhocID,     
             r.label            as AdhocLabel,      
             a.reportDataSource as AdhocDataSourceID,   
             t.AdhocDataSourceLabel 

    FROM   (SELECT id    as AdhocDataSourceID, 
                   label as AdhocDataSourceLabel 
    FROM public.jiresource       
    ) as t     

        INNER JOIN public.jiadhocdataview a ON a.reportDataSource = t.AdhocDataSourceID     
        INNER JOIN public.jiresource      r ON a.id = r.id
```

Notes:

- even though the tables appear with underscore (public_jiresource, the query only worked by substituting "." (public.jiresource).
- for some reason jasper doesn't like it when you use brackets; eg, a.id [AdhocID], thus I used a.id as AdhocID.

When you pull the derived table into an Adhoc View,

- create a table
- filter with resourcetype is one of SemanticLayerDataSource, AdhocDataView
- Colums: Resource Label, uri
- Groups: adhocdatasourcelabel